# Pegar tamanho da string dentro do array com PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou com o seguinte problema, no programa abaixo, eu pego os formulários de um site, mas tenho que especificar o tamanho exato da linha que possui o formulário(96), teria a possibilidade de pegar esse número sem ter que especificar manualmente.

```
<?php
         $url = file_get_contents('site.com');
         if(!$url) {
           trigger_error('Não foi possível ler a url', E_USER_NOTICE);
         }

         $var1 = explode("<form", $url);
         $string = array();

         // Pega o formulário do arquivo HTML.
         for($i = 0; $i < 96; $i++) {
            $string[0][$i] = $var1[1][$i];
         }

?>
```

Tentei usar o foreach, Mas não retorna o número certo.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($var1 as $valor => $detalhes) {
    foreach($detalhes as $detalhes => $saida) {
        $i++;       
     }
}
```

Grato!

Comment: Não entendi esse 96... seria oq?

Comment: É o tamanho linha do formulário html, ex: <form method="post" class="formulario" action=...>.

Comment: No total da 96 caracteres

Comment: Tenta assim `strlen($var1[1])`

Comment: A função pra pegar tamanho do array é `count( )`, e tamanho de strings tem `strlen( )` e `mb_strlen( )`

Comment: Opa, a função strlen funcionou! no caso ela pega até a ultima linha do arquivo html, mas resolvo com um if. Brigadão!

Comment: Acostume-se a dar uma lida no [manual do PHP](http://php.net), boa parte tem opção de português. Se der uma lida geral, vai pegar uma noção boa. Não falo só de pesquisar a função que você precisa, mas sim de uma lida geral pra saber onde achar o que precisa.

Comment: Sim, realmente ajuda muito. Vou tomar como total referência. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso não é pegar o tamanho da array, mas do índice da array que está selecionando.

Como o índice `[1]` da array `$var1` é uma string, você pode contar seu tamanho com a função **[strlen()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)**:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($var1[1]); $i++) {
   $string[0][$i] = $var1[1][$i];
}
```